# How can I clean Eclipse installation?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

1. How do you handle old/corrupted plugins in Eclipse?
2. What are some good ways to clean a current installation of Eclipse? (Juno, Kepler)
3. Are there any 3rd party software for that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can uninstall plugins which you have installed. This can be done using

```
About Eclipse -> Installation details -> Uninstall selected plugins
```

Comment: Or you can just delete the entire Eclipse installation and replace it with a fresh one.